# QT 4.8.x and VS2012 prebuilt binaries?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, qt4

I've been googling around to search if someone uploaded a rar file (or similar) with qt 4.8.x stuff compiled with MSVS 2012.

I've only seen people who compiled it (previos patching a source file).

But that is not an option in my case as I use Windows only in VM, so it will take ages.

Does someone know or can point me to download it or someone who compiled it for 2012 version can upload it?

Comment: The question is not useful because it attracts link-only answers. And your self-answer is not valid anymore because the link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally (after some hours searching) found it:

http://www.tver-soft.org/qt64

They have also 64bit builds, in case someone is interested also.

Comment: This website no longer exists, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Qt64-NG on sourceforce offered some pre-built Qt (4.8.4 ~ 5.5.0) binaries (x86 and x64) for MinGW, VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/qt64ng/?source=navbar)

Unfortunately, this project is closed.

But it is still accessible.

Comment: The question has been asked one year ago. And the OP actually found it out by himself / herself. Your link might get broken and thus will not be usable in the future.

Comment: @Martin Zabel The link OP posted is not accessible any more and people may still need a binary for Qt (like user Cory Quammen and me). The link I provided (although the project is closed) is still accessible as of Feb 23, 2016. Given this, I believe it will/could help whoever needs to download the binary from now on to whenever the link becomes unavailable.

Comment: I understand your point. But, the rules on  StackOverflow require to [quote the most relevant part of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) which is not possible here. Your link might get broken the same way as the link from the OP. That's why I found your answer not useful.